# Can an Ant build script to reference the Eclipse plugin folder without full path details?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I could use the following:

```
<fileset dir="C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\myplugin">
    <include name="extraStuff.jar" />
</fileset>
```

But that breaks the build file on someone else's PC who did not install eclipse into the default folder.

In my case I can't use *basedir* without hard folder references.

Is there a 'shortcut' to the eclipse install folder that I can use from ant running in eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the getOuputPath. Have a look at [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ant4eclipse/).

Comment: The referenced link is not found (404) on the HTTP server.